# how can i get the data encryption algorithm sent from android app without decompile it

Tags: android, wireshark

I want to make transactions directly through the API in the android application, the API has been found, the problem is when accessing the API must send encrypted data, how to find the algorithm for the encrypted data, the application I mean is

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digital.indosat.dealerapp

[jadx-gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXnwz.png)

As seen above in the AndroidManifest loading the source code at the path com.ooredoo.dealer.app.LoginOptions, but when I look at that path there are only 4 files, the source code for LoginOptions and the others is missing, and after I checked further this ProtectedOoredooApplication loads native code named libdexprotector.so

[data sent from android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVOEz.png)

And this is encrypted data sent from the application

FYI, I have gotten some of the required encryption from a guy who has tried this app too, he told me he used 'tcp snipping' to see the encryption algorithm, is that possible?

I hope you can tell me how to use 'tcp snipping' correctly, thank you

Comment: Can you say what specific application you want to talk to?
And do you have a capture of the network traffic?
There you might see the initialization part of the connection and the used crypto.

Comment: thanks for responding, I've updated the details of the question